# Dynamically load content based on page language

Tags: jquery, if-statement, load

I'm using an external system which has the following element to set languages:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">
```

We have the following languages:

```
en-US, en-GB, fr-FR, de-DE, es-ES, pl-PL, and pt-BR
```

We can create custom pages and I would like to use jQuery .load() to load different content based on the value of the "content" attribute.

For example:

```
IF "content=fr-FR" THEN $('#support-info').load('support-info-fr.html');
```

I am by no means a web developer (I'm more of a copy/paste/edit kind of guy). I've been searching for hours and found the if/else jQuery syntax but I can't seem to put it all together.

Hopefully, I've provided all the information needed and made it as clear as I can. Can anyone point me in the right direction/help me out? It would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the meta tag easily with a basic selector. Then use a switch case statement to set the page you want to load.  Then just load the page like you have above.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var lang = $('meta[http-equiv="Content-Language"]').attr('content');
  var page = '';
  switch(lang) {
    case 'en-US':
    page = 'support-info-en.html'
    break;
    case 'fr-FR':
    page = 'support-info-fr.html'
    break;
    //Add all possibilities
  }
  $('#support-info').load(page);
});
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [attribute selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
const contentLanguage = $('[http-equiv="Content-Language"]').attr('content')

if (contentLanguage == 'fr-FR') {
  $('#support-info').load('support-info-fr.html');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">
```

**OR**

```js
if ($('[http-equiv="Content-Language"][content="fr-FR"]').length) {
  $('#support-info').load('support-info-fr.html');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-US">
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!